# Negative commandments that only apply to women?

Tags: mitzvah, women

Are there any *mitzvos lo sa'aseh* that only apply to women?

Comment: Jonathan, welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish by clicking "register," above.

Comment: slightly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10540/why-are-women-exempt-from-many-time-bound-mitzvot

Answer (score 11):

The [Sefer Hachinuch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_ha-Chinuch) lists

- the prohibition of women lying with animals (#211) separately from the general prohibition of men lying with animals (#210).
- that a Chalalah may not eat הקדש -- holy food (#304)
- the prohibition of a woman wearing men's clothing (#564) separately from the prohibition of a man wearing women's clothing (#565)